# SQL/PL-SQL SELECT: Seleccionar multiples rows en una misma tabla

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, sql, select

estoy tratando de como hacer un query para seleccionar multiples renglones de una tabla especificando solo 3 registros, intenté con:
`SELECT NAME FROM EQUIPMENT_PLACES WHERE NAME = '68', '69','70';`
Al final me tira error de syntaxis. Dejo el ejemplo de una tabla donde estoy tratando de aplicar el query.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La clausula para esto es `IN` ej: `SELECT * FROM EQUIPMENT_PLACES WHERE NAME IN ('68', '69','70');`

Comment: Gracias, esta clausula me funcionó

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás seguro de que quieres acceder al atributo "Name"? No tendría sentido hacer una búsqueda por ese atributo y luego imprimir el mismo atributo.
Has intentado hacer:

```
SELECT * FROM EQUIPMENT_PLACES WHERE NAME = '68', '69','70';
```